# No upload button in a chat

Tags: support, chat

When entering a chat I do not see the updload button next to the send button as my conversation partner does. I tried with firefox and chrome (both v.110) and I did not use the mobile site (which was already mentioned as a problem in the past) ...??

This is what it looks like for me in chat:

[image]

And this is what it should look like (received from someone else):

[image]

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297058/can-a-user-with-20-100-reputation-still-upload-a-picture-into-chat-possible-bu

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you ;-)